# Call variables in construct function from other functions in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the code below below

```
public fucntion __construct(){
parent::__construct();
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['staff_no'] = $session_data['staff_no'];
     $data['staff_email'] = $session_data['staff_email'];
     $data['staff_fname'] = $session_data['staff_fname'];
     $data['staff_lname'] = $session_data['staff_lname'];
     $data['staff_level'] = $session_data['staff_level'];
        }
else
{
redirect('login','refresh');
}
```

Now, i have another function below

```
public function index()
{
$staff_no=$this->staff_no;

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('accounts/left-nav');
    $this->load->view('accounts/top-nav');
    $this->load->view('accounts/home');
    $this->load->view('footer',$staff_no);
}
```

***$staff_no*** variable above is meant to get the ***$data['staff_no']=$session_data['staff_no'];*** located in the __construct function but getting the error as undefined variable ***staff_no***
Kindly help

Comment: Is the index function a member of the same class?

Comment: Yes it is. And, thanks....The answer below by MrCode worked out

Comment: You should mark it as the accepted answer then so that it's flagged as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `$this->staff_no`, you've set a local variable `$data['staff_no']` in the constructor.

If you want to access the variable in other methods of the class, you need to store it in a property:

Constructor:

```
$this->staff_no = $session_data['staff_no'];
```

Comment: Thank you brother. This one worked out though I had to change the way I call it from index function as $staff_no=$this->staff_no; to $staff_no['staff_no']=$this->staff_no;